# Docker Compose ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker running on a centOS VM.

All of a sudden my docker stopped working.

When running docker-compose up, I get the following error every time:

> Creating network "nginx-php" with the default driver ERROR: could not
> find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the
> defaults to assign to the network

I tried uninstalling Docker and reinstalling it, but that didn't help.

**docker network ls**

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
ab8bed8d0def        bridge              bridge              local
eaf1f1928b69        host                host                local
a1e3c9baf283        none                null                local
```